# Change default page to yes from NA in cockpit expanded search of hybris?

Tags: xml, content-management-system, frontend, sap-commerce-cloud

When we open cms cockpit in hybris and expand the search option. It shows the "Is default page" radio button as n/a. I want to change it to "true" or "false". In which file should i make the changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every boolean entity in hybris, if is optional by virtue of its declaration in the items.xml, renders the n/a radio button when viewed in the hmc/cmscockpit.

To remove this, you need to do the following changes

- Go to items.xml of your extension
- Edit the boolean attribute as below:

```html
<attribute qualifier="active" type="java.lang.Boolean">
  <modifiers read="true" write="true" optional="false" />
  <defaultvalue>java.lang.Boolean.TRUE</defaultvalue>
  <persistence type="property" />
</attribute>
```

- Go to hmc.xml of your custom extension and make the below entries (if you want only yes/no to appear and do not want a checkbox)

```html
<attribute name="active">
  <advancedbooleaneditor truename="true" falsename="false" />
</attribute>
```

- Do *ant clean all* and start the hybris server
- Go to hmc/cockpit and view the attribute now. The attribute will look like below.
  [image]

Hope this helps